# instanciar cada vez un objeto con photon

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estoy haciendo un juego en el que hay dos bandos es un juego multijugador creado con unity y photon. Lo que yo quería que cuando se conecte el primer jugador que este sea poli y cuando se conecte el segundo jugador ese le tocara ser ladrón, lo he intentado de la siguiente manera pero no me funcionó:

```
public class instanciar : MonoBehaviour,IPunObservable
{
    public int i = 0;
    public string nombrePrefabEnResources = "ladron1";
    public string nombrePrefabEnResourcespoli = "police1";

    void IPunObservable.OnPhotonSerializeView(PhotonStream stream, PhotonMessageInfo info)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(nombrePrefabEnResources, new Vector3(20f + i, 0f, 65f), Quaternion.identity, 0);
            i++;
            Debug.Log("cargue");
        }
        else
        {
            PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(nombrePrefabEnResourcespoli, new Vector3(20f + i, 0f, -70f), Quaternion.identity, 0);
            i++;
        }

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

También lo he intentado con un bool pero tampoco.